# Sprite-Kit: moving an SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

i know that it's not that hard to move an object, but mine is different, i tried various ways none of them worked..

What i want to achieve?

- If the user taps the left side of the screen, the ball would go left
- If the user taps the right side of the screen, the ball would go right

So i went straight to the `touchesBegan` and wrote the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        ball?.removeAllActions()
       for touch in touches {

         let moveBY = SKAction.moveTo(x: touch.location(in: view).x, duration: 1.0)
        self.ball?.run(moveBY)
    } 
}
```

i tried four different ways, i couldn't get over it, also for your reference, here's a photo of my ball's
info:

[image: info]

Comment: You are getting the touch location in your view,  you need the touch location on the scene

Comment: I am also not convinced that self.ball is not nil

Comment: `here's a photo of my ball` ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) (I couldn't resist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to move a node in a direction you want, you first have to know three things

1. the `anchorPoint` of the node you want to move
2. the `anchorPoint` of the parent node of the node you want to move
3. the `position` of node you want to move

The `anchorPoint` property of the nodes store its values in normalised way from (0, 0) to (1, 1). Defaults to (0.5, 0.5) for `SPSpriteNode`

The `position` property of a node store its position as (x, y) coordinates in a ortogonal coordinate system **in which the point (0, 0) is positioned where the anchor point of the PARENT is.**

So your scene's `anchorPoint` is (0.5, 0.5) meaning if you place a direct child in it at coordinates (0, 0), the child will be positioned so that its `anchorPoint` is located at (0, 0) which will always match its parent's `anchorPoint`.

When you are using those overloads touchesBegan, touchesMoved, etc... inside `SKScene` or `SKNodes` as a general, if you want to get the position of touch represented in the coordinate system in which all direct children of scene(sknode) are situated, you should do something like

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)
        let rect = SKSpriteNode(color: .green, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        addChild(rect)
        rect.name = "rect"

        // don't pay attention to these two i need them because i dont have .sks file
        size = CGSize(width: 1334, height: 750)
        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: touch.location(in: self), duration: 1)
        childNode(withName: "rect")?.run(moveAction)
    }
}
```

hope it was helpful, other problems that you may have is that your ball is not direct child of scene, and you get its coordinates wrong

Comment: you are getting location(in: view) instead of location(in: self) which will give you wrong coordinates. view's coordinates is according to UIKit's coord system which is different from the SpriteKit one.